# Loop through a List Object (List<Message> messageTobeSent) to add values to one of the object properties

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

I Have a Model class Message

```
public class LetterMessage implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String variableName;
private short variableId;
private Integer dataType;
private Integer isRequired;
private String value;

    public LetterMessage() {
    super();
}


public LetterMessage(String variableName,String value) {
    super();
    this.variableName = variableName;
    this.value = value;
}


public LetterMessage(String variableName, short variableId,
                     Integer dataType, Integer isRequired, String value) {
    super();
    this.variableName = variableName;
    this.variableId = variableId;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.isRequired = isRequired;
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

for a given message there can be multiplevariable names like:
for Message = 101

```
VariableName: Address, AccountID, UniqueIdentifier.
VariableID: 001, 002, 003.
DatatypeID: 2, 1, 3.
isRequired: 1, 0, 1.
Value: ?, ?, ?.
```

I am getting the VariableName, DataType, is required from database in another class.

This for loop is getting the variables for the message ID and insert all that in to a LetterMessage List Object.

```
@Service
public class LetterRecoveryValidator {

List<CorrespondenceLetterVariableLog> letterDataHooks = correspondenceLetterVariableLogDao.findByLetterTypeId(letterTypeId);

List<LetterMessage> allDataHooks = new ArrayList<>();

for(CorrespondenceLetterVariableLog letterDataHook: letterDataHooks) {
        LetterMessage datahook = new LetterMessage();
        datahook.setVariableId(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableId());
        datahook.setVariableName(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableName());
        datahook.setDataType(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getCorrespondenceVariableDataTypeLookup().getLetterDataTypeId());
        datahook.setIsRequired(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableRequiredIndicator());
        allDataHooks.add(datahook);
    }
return allDataHooks;
}
```

This LetterRecoveryValidator is a independent class. I am not supposed to make any updates to it to add Value.

I have to use the Output and add the Value on my side.

I am calling it in my main class like below

```
List<LetterMessage> letterToBeSent = new ArrayList<>();

letterToBeSent=(letterRecoveryValidator.getLetterDataHooks(fulfillmentOption.getTemplateId()));
```

The above step will not have any data in the Value property
It will look something like below.

```
[LetterMessage [variableName=Address, variableId=001, dataType=2, isRequired=1, value=null], 
LetterMessage [variableName=RTLtr_CustomerAddress2, variableId=29, dataType=2, isRequired=1, value=null], 
LetterMessage [variableName=RTLtr_CustomerCity, variableId=30, dataType=2, isRequired=1, value=null], 
LetterMessage [variableName=RTLtr_CustomerState, variableId=33, dataType=2, isRequired=1, value=null], 
LetterMessage [variableName=RTLtr_CustomerZip, variableId=34, dataType=7, isRequired=1, value=null], 
LetterMessage [variableName=RTLtr_CoBorrowerName, variableId=78, dataType=2, isRequired=0, value=null]]
```

I need to add data to Value property.

I tried

```
letterToBeSent.add(new LetterMessage(MessageConstant.Address,"1243 WindHeaven Pkwy"));
```

Here GetAccountID() I am retrieving from Database

```
letterToBeSent.add(new LetterMessage(MessageConstant.AccountID,GetAcctID()));

letterToBeSent.add(new LetterMessage(MessageConstant.UniqueIdentifier,UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

Because I a, using "new LetterMessage" every time I am adding the value it is adding a new record with all the properties.

but I want it to insert the value in the Value property not create a new instance.

Comment: I updated my question with the proper requirements

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "value" property when setting all the fields to your entity. Try using this:

```
for(CorrespondenceLetterVariableLog letterDataHook: letterDataHooks) {
            LetterMessage datahook = new LetterMessage();
            datahook.setVariableId(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableId());
            datahook.setVariableName(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableName());
            datahook.setDataType(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getCorrespondenceVariableDataTypeLookup().getLetterDataTypeId());
            datahook.setIsRequired(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableLookup().getVariableRequiredIndicator());

            // Here is the fix:
            datahook.setValue(letterDataHook.getCorrespondenceVariableDataTypeLookup().getValue());

            allDataHooks.add(datahook);

            return allDataHooks;
    }
```

Comment: Value is not coming from the same table. First we have to get the list of variable names for given Message ID. This class is independent and I cannot make any changes to it to retrieve value. I have to only make use of it. And once I have the list of variable names then I have to fetch the value and add it to the Message Object list.